# Shortcut in Underscore/Lodash to (recursively) set all properties of an object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to rock a more functional style, and would like to set all properties of an object (and if possible sub-objects) to a specific value, e.g. `false` inplace. Is there a shortcut or do I have to iterate over the properties?

```
var obj = {
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: true,
  ...
  z: true
}
```

Transforms into:

```
var obj = {
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: false,
  ...
  z: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use underscore for the more functional style.

You can iterate over your object if missing you can change or if it sub-object reiterate and change every missing sub-object properties.

```js
function remap(object, missingValue, suppliedValue){
  var keys= _.keys(object);
  return _.reduce(keys, function(memo, key){
      memo[key] = object[key];
      if(memo[key] === missingValue){
         memo[key] = suppliedValue;

      }
      if(_.isObject(memo[key])){
        memo[key] = remap(memo[key],missingValue,suppliedValue);
      }
      return memo;
  }, {});
}

var h = {val : 3, b : undefined, d : undefined , k : {
  a: false, b: undefined
}, c: function(){ console.log(a);}};

console.log(remap(h,undefined,false));
```

If you need more complex check for comparing values then use the below function.

```js
function remap(object, complexCheck){
  var keys= _.keys(object);
  return _.reduce(keys, function(memo, key){
      memo[key] = object[key];
      memo[key] = complexCheck(memo[key]);
    if(_.isObject(memo[key])){
      memo[key] = remap(memo[key],complexCheck);
    }
    return memo;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: I guess I haven't looked under the hood enough yet at the underscore library. I was curious about why to use _.keys() though. In my testing, it returned all an object's members (including things like "length") whereas I only wanted my own property names. For that reason, wouldn't it be best to used getOwnPropertyNames() ?

Comment: you want to iterate over hash, not on array [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames)

Comment: Either I'm not understanding what you mean or you're not understanding me. If you perform a _.keys() on an object, you'll get members which you may not desire, like methods on the prototype chain, .length, etc. Using getOwnPropertyNames() instead of _.keys() avoids that problem, or if you were iterating through the results of _.keys() you could also do a _.has() to filter off the unwanted members.

Comment: you are right, _.keys already do a _.has check [inside](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-80)

Answer (score 0):

I've written something similar for performing a regex replace on fields nested within my object which matched a given pattern. I then mixed it into the underscore/lodash object so I could use it like you're wanting to do.

Modified for your purposes it could look something like this:

```
function(obj) {
    var $this = this,
        checkField = function(field) {
            if (typeof field === "undefined" || field === null || typeof field === "boolean") {
                return false;
            } else {
                return field;
            }
        },
        checkObject = function(obj) {
            if (obj instanceof Object) {
                Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).forEach(function (val) {
                    if (obj[val] instanceof Array) {
                        obj[val] = checkArray(obj[val]);
                    } else if (obj[val] instanceof Object) {
                        obj[val] = checkObject(obj[val]);
                    } else {
                        obj[val] = checkField(obj[val]);
                    }
                });
                return obj;
            } else if (obj instanceof  Array) {
                return checkArray(obj);
            } else {
                return checkField(obj);
            }
        },
        checkArray = function(arr) {
            if (arr instanceof Array) {
                arr.forEach(function(val) {
                    if (val instanceof Object) {
                        obj[val] = checkObject(val);
                    } else {
                        obj[val] = checkField(val);
                    }
                });
                return arr;
            } else {
                return arr;
            }
        };
    obj = checkObject(obj);
}
```

To add it as a mixin:

```
window._.mixin({
   setBoolsAndSuchToFalse: function(obj) {
      . . . . // The contents of the function from above
   }
});
```